# Can't access MySQL via command line

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, terminal

I've installed MySQL on a Mac OSX Snow Leopart but I am unable to launch it through the terminal:

```
$ mysql
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

With `$ echo $PATH`:

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

With this:

```
$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

It works but I am unable to use it with Ruby on Rails. So I guess there's something that I'm missing. My apologies if it isn't clearly explained.

Comment: You should absolutely not need to run the mysql command line tool from Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql`

should be

`/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin`

Path goes to directories and you need the `:` between entries.

You can also symlink mysql into something in your path

`ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql /usr/local/bin/mysql`

Comment: Thanks but How do I add : between entries and remove /mysql

Comment: what operating system and shell are you using?  Normally the path is set in your profile (This is shell specific)

Comment: thanks it finally work thank you.